# Close event for longClick menu in android

Tags: android, events, onlongclicklistener

In my android app I need to do some actions after close longClick menu.
I have the next code:

```
editText.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick (View v)
    {
         flag = "On";
         return false;
    }
});
```

And it works fine, but I need `flag="Off"` when longClick menu will be closed. Is it possible to catch this event?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you should use this:

```
@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    flag = "off";
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it looks that I hurried up... It works fine for app menu but not for longClick menu. Have you some ideas? Thanks.